# copy multiple files from listbox to specified folder

Tags: c#, listbox

there are in the files of my listbox ı want copy files these specified path for example c:\ or any path but error be (value cannot be null parameter name path) error how ı can copy specified path ı wirte this code

```
string source, fileToCopy, target;
string sourcefolder1;
string destinationfolder;
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(destinationfolder);
FileInfo[] annfiles;

foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
{
     fileToCopy = s;
     source = Path.Combine(sourcefolder1, fileToCopy);
     target = Path.Combine(destinationfolder, fileToCopy);
     File.Copy(source, target);

     annFiles = di.GetFiles();
}
```

Comment: More info are needed. can you paste the exception details and the row where exception is thrown?

Comment: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path

Comment: Directoryinfo di = new DirectoryInfo(destinationfolder); here value cannot be null parameter name path error..

Comment: You are not setting your `sourcefolder1` or `destindationfolder` values.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
string destinationfolder;
```

You declare an empty string and after try to get DirectoryInfo from what? And Empty string? This thrown an Exception. You can see your code like this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("");
```

This code throw always an Exception. 
The question is: what you need in "destinationFolder" parameter?

This is a sample file copy:

```
string sourceFolder = @"C:\Documents";
string destinationFolder = "@"C:\MyDocumentsCopy";

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
foreach(var file in files)
{
    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file.Name);
    File.Copy(file.Fullname, destinationPath);
}
```

Comment: which directory you want use? Without this information i'm not able to help you.

Comment: how ı can make this with listbox ı take from listbox files copy to specified path

Comment: First load files from target directory into your listbox. After handle management of listbox. You're asking for an entire program not only a question!